# How to show this is a Folner sequence?

Tags: group-theory

We defined a Folner sequence by the condition that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ | g A_n \Delta A_n |}{ | A_n|} = 0 $$ for all $g \in G$, where $\left\{A_n \right\}$ is a sequence of finite subsets of $G$.

**Problem:** Let $G = \mathbb{Z}$. Show that the sequence $(A_n)$ given by $$ A_n = \left\{0, \ldots, n-1 \right\} $$ is a Folner sequence.

Using this Folner sequence, explain how we can define a Folner sequence for the group $ \mathbb{Z}^k$ with $k \geq 2$.

**Attempt:** I think I have $$g A_n = \left\{ g, g+1, \ldots, g + n-1 \right\}. $$ Then I wish to know what $| g A_n \Delta A_n|$ equals for large $n$. Also, I have $| A_n| = n$.

Comment: To start with, if you're working in $\mathbf{Z}$ you'd better use an additive notation, so $gA_n$ should be $g+A_n$ instead.